# How to set the max number of open files in only one process?

Tags: c, linux, file-descriptor

OS controls the max number of open file discripters.

Is there any method that only a process sets a specific the max number of openfiles and, other processes only can use the traditional default max number of openfiles?

Comment: https://ss64.com/bash/ulimit.html sets the system wide limit

Comment: What is the purpose of C and C++ tags? If you want to set it from the process itself, say so in the question, and selwct just one language tag.

Comment: All limits set via `setrlimit` are process-wide and not system-wide. They are inherited by child process, but unrelated processes are not affected.

Comment: @hyde
I want to know weather the specific number setting of a specific process can be possible, in c or c++ code. c code is a good answer. In addition, I want to know if it is possible with C++ without c-style. I add this opinion to my post. Thank you for your comment.

Comment: @3088K That's two questions. It is not possible with either C or C++ with only standard library, you need platform specific features.

Comment: I removed the C++ part. Feel free to roll it back if you really want, but there is a good chance it will get downvoted, because it is asking for 2 solutions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.

A process can use `getrlimit` and `setrlimit` to limit the number of files it may open.

It operates on the current process.

A program that uses this can do a `fork`, use `getrlimit/setrlimit` and then do (e.g.) `execvp` to limit a child program.

---

Here is some code. The count reported will be 3 less because `stdin/stdout/stderr` are open.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/resource.h>

void
show(struct rlimit *rlim,const char *who)
{

    printf("rlim_cur=%d rlim_max=%d [%s]\n",
        rlim->rlim_cur,rlim->rlim_max,who);
}

int
main(int argc,char **argv)
{
    int err;
    struct rlimit rlim;

    --argc;
    ++argv;

    setlinebuf(stdout);
    setlinebuf(stderr);

    err = getrlimit(RLIMIT_NOFILE,&rlim);
    if (err < 0) {
        perror("getrlimit");
        exit(1);
    }

    show(&rlim,"original");

    if (argc > 0) {
        rlim.rlim_cur = atoi(*argv);
        err = setrlimit(RLIMIT_NOFILE,&rlim);

        if (err < 0) {
            perror("setrlimit");
            exit(1);
        }

        err = getrlimit(RLIMIT_NOFILE,&rlim);
        if (err < 0) {
            perror("setrlimit");
            exit(1);
        }
        show(&rlim,"setrlimit");
    }

    int count = 0;
    while (1) {
        int fd = open("/dev/null",O_RDONLY);
        if (fd < 0) {
            perror("open");
            break;
        }
        ++count;
    }

    printf("max open files: %d\n",count);

    return 0;
}
```

---

Normal output:

```
rlim_cur=1024 rlim_max=4096 [original]
open: Too many open files
max open files: 1021
```

---

Output with arg of 17:

```
rlim_cur=1024 rlim_max=4096 [original]
rlim_cur=17 rlim_max=4096 [setrlimit]
open: Too many open files
max open files: 14
```

Answer (score 1):

One way to change resource limits of a particular process using [prlimit](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/prlimit.1.html),

prlimit --pid `<PID>` --nofile=1024:4095

Internally prlimit makes use of system call [setrlimit()](https://linux.die.net/man/2/setrlimit) to set the limits.